# why web.config has predefined tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I just started reading XML,it says it has no predefined tags,then how come inside web.config we have predefined tags like ConectionString,appSettings etc?
Web.Config itself is written in XML format right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because it has a `Schema`. Look up `XML Schemas` in your favourite internet search engine and you'll find a whole new world! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Web.Config itself is written in XML format right?

Yes, but in addition to that it has an [XML schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) associated and the Configuration class which is responsible to read values from this XML file verifies that the schema is being respected.

You should make the distinction between `well formed XML` and `valid XML` according to a schema.